# How to call webpack from shell script and get errors

Tags: shell, npm, webpack, yeoman

I've made a toy app with this [yeoman react webpack generator](https://github.com/react-webpack-generators/generator-react-webpack), and I'd like to simplify the deployment process with a shell script.

A snippet of the package.json looks like this...

```
"scripts": {
  "clean": "rimraf dist/*",
  "copy": "copyfiles -f ./src/index.html ./src/favicon.ico ./dist",
  "dist": "npm run copy & webpack --env=dist",
```

With this, my current process is to commit changes (using git), then `npm run clean`, then `npm run dist`, then commit again with a release # commit message, really push to my toy production server with `git subtree push ...`

I'd like to automate this with a script.  Here's what I have so far:

First, I added an invocation of my script to package json...

```
...
"deploy": "./deploy2server.sh",
...
```

In deploy to server, I proceed only if there are uncommitted changes, and start my manual process, like this...

```
#!/bin/sh

if [[ -z $(git status -s) ]]
then
  npm run clean
  npm run dist
#
# My problem is here 
#
# want, if no errors in my code, commit and push subtree
else
  echo "must commit changes before running"
  exit
fi
```

My problem is that I need to detect errors and warnings *about my code* from webpack.  Webpack console output looks like this...

```
Hash: e4e23433b4c1b1ab7a97
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 6140ms
     Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    app.js   188 kB       0  [emitted]  main
app.js.map  1.95 MB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 231 hidden modules

WARNING in ./src/components/MyComponent.js

/Users/path_to_my_project/MyComponent.js
  19:13  warning  'j' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)


WARNING in app.js from UglifyJs
Condition always false [./~/fbjs/lib/invariant.js:26,0]
Dropping unreachable code [./~/fbjs/lib/invariant.js:27,0]
...a gazzillion more warnings like these, unrelated to my code
```

**How can my shell script find out if there are errors or warnings *in my code only* and proceed if there aren't any?**

The only idea I have is to pipe all of that output to a tmp file, then parse it looking for the errors/warnings I care about, but I don't really know how to write a parse like that (in grep?) and get a result back.

If it's any help, I figured out how to call webpack directly from the script, with `node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack --env=dist`, but I still don't know how to get the output or understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

7 views in more than a day?  Is there a badge for least popular question ever?

I solved the problem by learning about `set -e`, which tells the script to exit when any error occurs in the commands that follow.  Now my deployment script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [[ -z $(git status -s) ]]
then
  read -p "Deployment commit message: " message
  set -e
  npm run clean
  npm run dist
  git add -A
  git commit -m "$message"
  git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages
else
  echo "must commit changes before running"
  exit
fi
```

I'll use that deployment commit message to indicate version, or something easily searchable in the logs.